# How to serialize ArrayList<float[]> using Moshi JSON library for Android

Tags: moshi

I'm trying to convert a Java object to JSON using the Moshi library for Android.  The object contains a property of type

> ArrayList < float[]>

and I'm registering the following adapter to convert the object.

```
Type type = Types.newParameterizedType
        (List.class, HistoryPath.class, ArrayList.class, Float[].class, Float.class);

JsonAdapter<Drawing> adapter = moshi.adapter(type);

String json = adapter.toJson(drawing);
```

The "toJson" method fails with the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform
>   java.util.ArrayList annotated [] requires explicit
>   JsonAdapter to be registered
>                                                                                            at
>   com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.create(ClassJsonAdapter.java:50)
>                                                                                            at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:99)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.createFieldBindings(ClassJsonAdapter.java:90)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.create(ClassJsonAdapter.java:74)
>                                                                                            at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:99)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.createFieldBindings(ClassJsonAdapter.java:90)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.create(ClassJsonAdapter.java:74)
>                                                                                            at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:99)
>                                                                                            at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:57)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter.newArrayListAdapter(CollectionJsonAdapter.java:51)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter$1.create(CollectionJsonAdapter.java:35)
>                                                                                            at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:99)
>                                                                                            at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:57)

I think my type definitions are wrong but I can't seem to find the right value

Answer (score 12):

ArrayList is a platform type, as the error says.
You can use List (or make a custom JsonAdapter specifically for ArrayList).

Also, there's a problem here:
`Type type = Types.newParameterizedType(List.class, HistoryPath.class, ArrayList.class, Float[].class, Float.class);`

This type is `List<HistoryPath, ArrayList, Float[], Float>` which is invalid, and it will not yield the correct result for `JsonAdapter<Drawing> adapter = moshi.adapter(type);`.

You probably just want `JsonAdapter<Drawing> adapter = moshi.adapter(Drawing.class);`.

Comment: Getting a different error based on your suggestion:

ArrayList<com.rm.freedrawview.HistoryPath> annotated [] requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered

Comment: @androidguy ArrayList is a platform type. You need to register a JsonAdapter for it, or use List.

Answer (score 11):

Those who want to use `ArrayList` and Moshi

---

### **Solution 1**

You have to make adapters for every object you want to use.

```
class ThingArrayListMoshiAdapter {
    @ToJson
    fun arrayListToJson(list: ArrayList<Thing>): List<Thing> = list

    @FromJson
    fun arrayListFromJson(list: List<Thing>): ArrayList<Thing> = ArrayList(list)
}
```

usage

```
Moshi
    .Builder()
    .add(ThingArrayListMoshiAdapter())
    .build()
```

---

### **Solution 2**

Make a `JsonAdapter` for `ArrayList`, like Moshi's `CollectionJsonAdapter`

```
abstract class MoshiArrayListJsonAdapter<C : MutableCollection<T>?, T> private constructor(
    private val elementAdapter: JsonAdapter<T>
) :
    JsonAdapter<C>() {
    abstract fun newCollection(): C

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): C {
        val result = newCollection()
        reader.beginArray()
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            result?.add(elementAdapter.fromJson(reader)!!)
        }
        reader.endArray()
        return result
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: C?) {
        writer.beginArray()
        for (element in value!!) {
            elementAdapter.toJson(writer, element)
        }
        writer.endArray()
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$elementAdapter.collection()"
    }

    companion object {
        val FACTORY = Factory { type, annotations, moshi ->
            val rawType = Types.getRawType(type)
            if (annotations.isNotEmpty()) return@Factory null
            if (rawType == ArrayList::class.java) {
                return@Factory newArrayListAdapter<Any>(
                    type,
                    moshi
                ).nullSafe()
            }
            null
        }

        private fun <T> newArrayListAdapter(
            type: Type,
            moshi: Moshi
        ): JsonAdapter<MutableCollection<T>> {
            val elementType =
                Types.collectionElementType(
                    type,
                    MutableCollection::class.java
                )

            val elementAdapter: JsonAdapter<T> = moshi.adapter(elementType)

            return object :
                MoshiArrayListJsonAdapter<MutableCollection<T>, T>(elementAdapter) {
                override fun newCollection(): MutableCollection<T> {
                    return ArrayList()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

usage

```
Moshi
    .Builder()
    .add(MoshiArrayListJsonAdapter.FACTORY)
    .build()
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it into an array.

Let's assume you want to use an `arraylist : ArrayList<>`. You convert it into an array. `arraylist.toArray()`

Answer (score 1):

You can change ArrayList for MutableList and it works!