# Moshi Adapter ArrayList not allowed but List or MutableList is okay

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

Just started to work with Kotlin after a long run with Java, it seems there is a bit of changes when it comes to collections **ArrayList and List**. While working with Retrofit2 and RxJava with Moshi I noticed ArrayList is not an acceptable adapter only List, MutableList, and the rest mentioned [here](https://github.com/square/moshi#built-in-type-adapters). MutableList although not listed seems to work fine as well since it is an implementation of List but ArrayList also imeplements MutableList so I wonder why ArrayList will not work. Could someone explain it?

Comment: Have you already seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43863236/313870

Comment: Based on that question, you can't use ArrayList with Moshi in Java either. Kotlin's MutableList is a 1:1 counterpart to Java's List. Kotlin's plain List interface lacks any methods for mutating the contents.